# How do I start to incorporate reactJs into existing laravel app

Tags: reactjs, laravel-5

I have an application using laravel Frameworks 5.4.32 and I want to use reactJs for some sections of the app.  What are the steps to integrate reactJs into the application and start building with it?

I'm not looking to just use Laravel as a backend with api endpoints.  I'd still like to use the existing routing that the application already has through laravel, but I want to render some of the more dynamic elements using reactjs (such as a feed or notifications)

Comment: you can use laravel as backend for your app and react as view. so you need to create api endpoints for integration in frontend.

Comment: @TusharKotlapure The application already is using laravel for more than just api endpoints, I'd like to continue using it like it is but add things in and ontop of it with reactjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Laravel 5.5 now has reactjs integrated in but you have to be upgraded to php 7

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/frontend#using-react